# C++ best practice: write definitions for class methods in multiple .cpp files

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class with a lot of methods, declared in the same .h file

```
//myclass.h

class MyClass{

//Lots of public, private methods

}
```

What's the best way of writing the definitions of all this class' methods, which are a lot and require thousand lines of code ?

1. Create a myclass.cpp file for all these definitions
2. Create myclass1.cpp and myclass2.cpp to split these methods in a meaningful way and thus create shorter and easier to read files
3. Refactor this class in order to move some methods to another class (declared in a different .h file)

Thank you

Comment: #3. If your class does so much it's hard to even keep it all in a single file, it's a strong indication you don't follow the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Most probably 3. If a class has a lot of methods, it probably violates Single Responsibility principle (from SOLID). Try to split this class into multiple more meaningful ones.

Comment: Depening on the context, 3 or 1.

Comment: if you don't use LTO with your toolchain, most things should be kept in .h file.

Comment: @Klaus *"most"* depends heavily on what kinds of things the class contains. It would be a bad idea to keep functions that are changed often, or functions whose implementation has many dependencies in the header file.

Comment: @user2079303: Often changes are no argument for me. The result must be a small&fast executable. Compile time is no criteria as compile farms are common. Especially in embedded system is splitting content from the header a very bad idea.